# Video player in JUCE (C++) - building on Windows running on iOS

Tags: ios, windows, visual-studio, libvlc, juce

I'd like to know what is the simplest way to build a video playing app that runs under iOS. I'm using the [JUCE Framework](https://www.juce.com/) that allows to develop under Windows with e.g. Visual Studio and code programs for Android, iOS, etc.

I've looke around libVLC, FFMPEG and so on. But all of these are intended to be developed under Linux, I think.

Does somebody have an easy Example for **JUCE** to build an iOS player app working under Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

**Coding**

There's nothing to step you writing the code itself; IDEs are just fancy text editors with other tools built in (in the case of Visual Studio, a full code translation toolchain).

You'll probably find that things like code completion won't work, as JUCE will `#ifdef` parts of the codebase out depending on what project type you're launching, but last I checked (when I worked there) there was no Visual Studio iOS project exporter available, so you'll have to just use a Windows compatible one and program through that.

**Building**

In order to build an iOS app, you need a Mac. If you take a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn771552.aspx#AndroidHTML), it states:

> For iOS projects, connect to a networked Mac and start the Mac emulator from Visual Studio.

No cross-platform library that I know can circumvent this restriction; I believe it's due to a legal requirement enforced by Apple.

With that said, if you don't own a Mac you might be able to "rent" one using a service like [Mac In Cloud](http://www.macincloud.com/). I'm not a lawyer, some please make sure you check the legality of using such a cloud service for building iOS apps before doing so.

**Debugging**

Since you need to be able to compile in order to debug a specific build of the application, the section on building applies. Of course, there's nothing stopping you from debugging it without a build by reading the source code carefully, but I'm guessing that's not what you're asking about.

Comment: I know that I need a Mac for COMPILING. But not for coding.

Comment: My problem is, that I have to debug with Visual Studio under Windows. And I have probs with building the source code under Windows as the Libs are all intended for Linux.

Comment: @Christoph in order to debug a build, you need to compile it, so the building section is relevant there

Comment: @Christoph if you feel this answers your question, please mark as accepted  so it can be removed from the unanswered queue. If it doesn't answer your question, then please state what's wrong so I can improve it :)